# UpdatePanel and UpdatePanelAnimationExtender problem

Tags: asp.net

I want to display a progress animation while updatepanel's work being done, but without re-rendering updatepanel's content.

If I set ChildrenAsTriggers="false", the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender's onupdated script does not triggered (function onUpdated()).
If I set ChildrenAsTriggers="true", and click show div button, after the updating is completed, the updatepanel's content is re-rendered (and the div is hidden again).

My code:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHide(){
            var div = document.getElementById('div2');
            if (div.style.display=="none")
                div.style.display="";
            else
                div.style.display="none";


        }

            function onUpdating(){
               // get the update progress div
                var pnlPopup = document.getElementById("div2");                           

            }

            function onUpdated() {
                // get the update progress div
                var pnlPopup = $get("div2"); 
                // make it invisible

            }    

    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form11" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"> 
      <ContentTemplate>
        <input id="Button1" onclick="ShowHide();" type="button" value="Show Div (click first)" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Click"  />
&nbsp;<div id="div1" style="background-color:Red;width:700px;height:200px;"> </div>          
        <div id="div2" style="background-color:Blue;width:700px;height:500px;display:none;"></div>
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>       
   <cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1" TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
       <Animations>
           <OnUpdating>
               <Parallel duration="0" >        
                   <ScriptAction Script="onUpdating();" />  
               </Parallel>
           </OnUpdating>
             <OnUpdated>
              <Parallel duration="0">             
                 <ScriptAction  Script="onUpdated();"  /> 
              </Parallel> 
           </OnUpdated>
      </Animations>
   </cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>

 </form>
</body>

protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved the desired result using PageRequestManage, without UpdatePanelAnimationExtender or UpdateProgress.

```
 with (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()) {
         add_beginRequest(onUpdating);
         add_endRequest(onUpdated);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use updateProgress control instead of extending the updatePanel with UpdatePanelAnimationExtender.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

    </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                &nbsp;<img src="loading.jpg" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </form>


using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to activate onupdating script. it has a some calculation and positioning in it.

Comment: Even you can poisiton the Div tag or picture under the UpdateProgress control using the CSS, what calculation ur doing on that part ??

Comment: @solairaja, i can manage the positioning, but it doesn't work anyway, the panel gets rerendered.

Comment: try the example which i have given

Comment: and if u stil geting the panel rendering.. check your web.config for any missing tags.